# Compare 2 arrays of objects with Underscore to find the differnce

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays, one is newVal and the other is origVal define

orig:

```
[
{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1826692,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1833283,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":950000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1832134,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":850000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1829932,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":750000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1827548,"Rating":5,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"}
]
```

new:

```
[
{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":2,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1826692,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1833283,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":950000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1832134,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":850000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1829932,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":750000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1827548,"Rating":5,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"}
]
```

If I change one of the ratings in new, how might I detect that change, and retrieve the changed object?

There will only be one change at a time, although I don't think that matters.

FYI: These arrays are being produced from an Anjularjs  watchcollection

```
$scope.$watchCollection('items', function (new, old) {

}, true);
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Are those the same objects in the array (i.e. `===` identity) or are they only similar-looking?

Comment: What result do you need? The index of the changed object in the array, the new changed object, the old changed object, the rating?

Comment: I would prefer the changed object ie {"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":2,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look to this:

```
var a = [
{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1826692,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1833283,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":950000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1832134,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":850000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1829932,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":750000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1827548,"Rating":5,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"}
];

var b = [
{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":2,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1826692,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1833283,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":950000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1832134,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":850000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1829932,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":750000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1827548,"Rating":5,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"}
]

var difference = function(array){
   var rest = Array.prototype.concat.apply(Array.prototype, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

   var containsEquals = function(obj, target) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    return _.any(obj, function(value) {
      return _.isEqual(value, target);
    });
  };

  return _.filter(array, function(value){ return ! containsEquals(rest, value); });
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(difference(b, a)));
> [{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":2,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"}]
```

The code is based on the original function [difference](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) from underscore, but it performs a deep comparison between objects using [isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual).

Comment: It's brilliant, what it does. I wish I could understand the code.

Answer (score 4):

If the order does not change, a simple iteration will do it. Underscore provides the [`find` method](http://underscorejs.org/#find) for this task:

```
var changedObj = _.find(newVal, function(obj, index) {
    return obj.Rating != oldVal[index].Rating;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Jonathan's answer, I have tweaked a version that returns a usable list of differences including which side had diff and the index of the record.

```
var a = [
{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1826692,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1833283,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":950000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1832134,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":850000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1829932,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":750000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1827548,"Rating":5,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"}
];

var b = [
{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":2,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1826692,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1833283,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":950000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1832131,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":850000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1829932,"Rating":4,"ListPrice":750000,"PropertyType":"Residential"},
{"ListingId":1827548,"Rating":5,"ListPrice":650000,"PropertyType":"Residential"}
]

function diff(arr1, arr2){
    var aDiffs=[]
    function __comp(arrL, arrR, side){
        var rL, rR, bFound
        for(var i=0;i<arrL.length;i++){rL=arrL[i]
            bFound=false
            for(var j=0;j<arrR.length;j++){rR=arrR[j]
                if (_.isEqual(rL, rR)){ 
                    bFound=true
                    break
                }
            }
            if (!bFound)aDiffs.push({side: side, ind: i, obj: rL})
        }
    }
    __comp(arr1, arr2, 'l')
    __comp(arr2, arr1, 'r')
    return aDiffs
};


console.log(JSON.stringify(diff(b, a)).replace(/},{/g, "}\n,{"));
```

Output:

```
[{"side":"l","ind":0,"obj":{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":2,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"}}
,{"side":"l","ind":3,"obj":{"ListingId":1832131,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":850000,"PropertyType":"Residential"}}
,{"side":"r","ind":0,"obj":{"ListingId":1762276,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":7411828,"PropertyType":"Residential"}}
,{"side":"r","ind":3,"obj":{"ListingId":1832134,"Rating":3,"ListPrice":850000,"PropertyType":"Residential"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
const current = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'},{name:'c'}]
const update = [{name:'x'},{name:'a'},{name:'b'},{name:'f'}]
const records = current.concat(update);
const diff = {};
diff.in = []
diff.out = [];
records.forEach(item => {
  if(!current.find(cur => item.name == cur.name))diff.in.push(item)
  if(!update.find(up => item.name == up.name ))diff.out.push(item)
})
```