# How to compare objects of arrays and return unique array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

First array:

```
generalInfo = [{"fName": "Suku", "lName": "Brown", "sex": "Male", "Id": "RY12S"}, {"fName": "Mary", "lName": "Sue", "sex": "Female", "Id": "UT72W"}]
```

Second array:

```
paymentInfo = [{"Id": "RY12S", "amount": "1000.00", "purpose": "rent", "date": "2017-17-07"}, {"Id": "UT72W", "amount": "5000.00", "purpose": "renovation", "date": "2017-15-07"}]
```

Now, I want to be able to compare the Id field for the both arrays and return their unique information.

At least the third should look like this:

```
specificInfo = [{"Id": "RY12S","fName": "Suku", "lName": "Brown", "amount": "1000.00", "purpose": "rent"}, {"Id": "UT72W","fName": "Mary", "lName": "Sue", "amount": "5000.00", "purpose": "renovation"}]
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? It's expected you at least try, then when/if you have issues, we're happy to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.push() if does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist)

Comment: This is duplicate question. You can check this for your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988349/array-push-if-does-not-exist

Comment: Possible dublicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383636/compare-2-arrays-of-objects-with-underscore-to-find-the-differnce

Answer (score 0):

An ES6 solution with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var generalInfo = [{"fName": "Suku", "lName": "Brown", "sex": "Male", "Id": "RY12S"}, {"fName": "Mary", "lName": "Sue", "sex": "Female", "Id": "UT72W"}];

var paymentInfo = [{"Id": "RY12S", "amount": "1000.00", "purpose": "rent", "date": "2017-17-07"}, {"Id": "UT72W", "amount": "5000.00", "purpose": "renovation", "date": "2017-15-07"}];

var uniqueInfo = generalInfo.map((generalItem) => {
  var paymentItem = paymentInfo.find((item) => item.Id === generalItem.Id);

  return {
    Id: generalItem.Id,
    fName: generalItem.fName,
    lName: generalItem.lName,
    amount: paymentItem.amount,
    purpose: paymentItem.purpose
  };
});

console.log(uniqueInfo);
```

Try to understand the logic behind this and, if you need to implement in ES5, try to do by yourself before posting here.